# Do.call to execute a function on columns of data frame

Tags: r

How can I call the the "fun" function on an entire data frame. I am trying using do.call. Any ideas?

```
fun<-function(x,y,z){
  if(x == "a"){
    return(paste("first",y,z))
  }else if(x == "b"){
    return(paste("second",y,z))
  }else
  {
    return(paste("thrid",y,z))
  }
}

d1<-c("a","b","c")
d2<-c("b","b","c")
d3<-c("c","b","c")
dat<-data.frame(d1,d2,d3)
colnames(dat)<-c("header1","header2","header3")
fun("b","b","c") #here is an example of the function call

#now I want to call the fundtion on the data frame and put it in a new column
dat$newcolumn<- do.call(fun,dat$header1, dat$header2,dat$header3 ) 

#results should be 
"first b c"
"second b c"
"third b c"
```

which is the same as

```
fun(dat$header1[1],dat$header2[1],dat$header3[1]) 
fun(dat$header1[2],dat$header2[2],dat$header3[2]) 
fun(dat$header1[3],dat$header2[3],dat$header3[3])
```

But I want do.call to do that for me.

Comment: The second argument to `do.call` needs to be a list which `dat$header1` is not. You need to explain what 'y' and 'z' are supposed to be assigned to in `fun`. I'm guessing they should be something in the data.frame but it's not clear.

Comment: This is a toy example. Y and Z are not assigned anything. I want to pass the 3 columns to do call and get a new column. That new column should be the result of passing each row  in each of the 3 columns through the fun function. See my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close, using apply on each row does the trick:

```
apply(dat,1,function(u) fun(u[1],u[2],u[3]))
```

However, according to the definition of your function, the result should be:

```
[1] "first b c"  "second b b" "thrid c c"
```

If you want the result you wrote, you just redefine your dataframe like this:

```
dat = as.data.frame(t(dat))
```

Since you want an example with `do.call`:

```
var = "fun"
apply(dat,1,function(u) do.call(var, list(u[1],u[2],u[3])))
```

Comment: Thank you! ...but can't do.call do this?

Comment: do.call() is used when you want to apply a function stored in a variable, as a string for example, to some variables. Here your function is defined explicitely but I will give you an example with do.call.

Comment: Thank you I would appreciate a do.call example.